# Is it possible to recover a deleted note on Notes app?

Tags: notes

I was using the [Notes snap package](https://snapcraft.io/notes) on Ubuntu 18.04 and I accidentally erased one valuable note I've been working on. I've been looking at forums on how to recover it (if possible) but so far I haven't found anything.

Does anyone have a clue if it's possible to recover this, and if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you mean  [this app](https://snapcraft.io/notes)? Which version? [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/notesapp/comments/a93z3x/deleted_notes/) might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the app and I actually entered here /snap/notes/4/.config/Awesomeness and found about 95% of the deleted file.